# C#: Stop loop until an event

Tags: c#, events, loops, for-loop, load

I have a `for` loop and inside there is a navigate method for a browser. and it's suppose to load diffrent sites, but the problem is that it will start to load 1 site and before it will load it, it'll load another site. so I need to like pause it until it's completed.

I started to write an event to when the ProgressChanged event is at 100%.. than I figured I don't have any idea what to do next but I think it's a start.
Please help, Thanks!

Edit: I am using Forms as Roland said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are doing windows forms programming. The event you want is [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) Here's an example:

```
public Uri MyURI { get; set; }

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyURI = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com");
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    webBrowser1.Url = MyURI;
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Url == MyURI)
        MessageBox.Show("Page Loaded");
}
```

For a list of URIs it's straight forward.

```
public int CurrentIndex = 0;
List<Uri> Uris;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Uris = new List<Uri> { new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"), new Uri("http://google.com/") };

    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

    webBrowser1.Url = Uris[CurrentIndex];
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    if (e.Url == Uris[CurrentIndex])
    {
        CurrentIndex++;
        if (CurrentIndex < Uris.Count)
        {
            browser.Url = Uris[CurrentIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Roland , but I need help with the loop.
I need to make it wait until the document is completed, and only than repeat it self

Comment: @Roland Thanks, but I had a problem using this. I'm writing this inside a class as a function, and I tried using e.Url but it's read only and im not quite sure how to wriet a new url.

@Mathieu It will waste some time and I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Ken, you are not supposed to set the e.Url variable. I'm including it in only because it will avoid too many callbacks, such as iframes, from loading a single web page. If you want a reference to the webBrowser1 and you don't have direct access, you can get it from casting the sender: WebBrowser webBrowser1 = (WebBrowser)sender; right below the function definition: webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted

Comment: @Roland sorry for the newbie questions but how can I cast the sender if it's webBrowser? inside the function it's inside the parameters (which I can't do in this `_DocumentCompleted` function)